# FAST Search Crawl fails on local file system with error 0x80040d07

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, fast-esp, fastsearch

I've successfully installed Sharepoint 2010 and FAST Search for Sharepoint 2010 on my machine.  Things seem to work fine with crawl of sharepoint sites but crawling local file system keeps failing with below:

```
The start address unknown://win-fs/C:/Users/ravish/FAST_TEST_SET cannot be crawled.

Context: Application 'FAST_Content_SSA', Catalog 'Portal_Content'

Details:
    Item not crawled due to one of the following reasons: Preventive crawl rule; Specified content source hops/depth exceeded; URL has query string parameter; Required protocol handler not found; Preventive robots directive.   (0x80040d07)
```

I got this from Event View Application log.  I have made sure permissions are set to allow read, list and execute access to users running the services.  Also tried updating crawl rules etc. to make them very liberal.

The URLs I have tried in Content Source are:
//win-fs/C:/Users/ravish/FAST_TEST_SET
file://win-fs/C:/Users/ravish/FAST_TEST_SET
file:\win-fs\C:\Users\ravish\FAST_TEST_SET

Nothing seems to work so far.  Have been toiling the web trying to find answers, found many users with similar problems but nothing concrete with a straight reply to it.  I've spent hours so any help will be appreciated.

Details of my system:
Windows Server 2008 R2
Sharepoint Enterprise 2010
FAST Search 2010

(all installed on single laptop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I got it now, rebooted the machine and tried following format and voila it worked!

file://WIN-FS/Users/ravish/FAST_TEST_SET

Can't believe how fussy SP is about paths!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the sharepoint version of fast, but i think the crawler is mostly the same as the one in previous version of standalone fast.  in which case - i'd guess that by itself it won't be able to crawl the filesystem as it's built to process and crawl via http & html... parsing pages, following links, etc.

You might be able to setup a local webserver & allow directory indexes and then crawl the 'site' that way. or you might be able to use the webserver embedded in [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) and again... crawl the local site (or desired subset).

Comment: I don't think this is right.  FAST for sharepoint is quite clearly supposed to be able to crawl files on disk.  It show example urls right in the interface, but can't seem to get to work for the reason I mentioned.